# Unable to run Keras with GPU on AWS EC2

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-ec2, keras

I'm trying to use a g2.2xlarge EC2 instance to train some simple ml models but I'm not sure if GPU support is working. I'm afraid not since the training times are very similar to my crappy laptop.

I've installed Tensorflow GPU support [following these official guidelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#NVIDIARequirements) and the following are the outputs of some commands.

Running `nvidia-smi` in the shell returns

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.37                 Driver Version: 396.37                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GRID K520           On   | 00000000:00:03.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   29C    P8    17W / 125W |      0MiB /  4037MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Running `pip list`

```
...
jupyterlab (0.31.5)
jupyterlab-launcher (0.10.2)
Keras (2.2.2)
Keras-Applications (1.0.4)
Keras-Preprocessing (1.0.2)
kiwisolver (1.0.1)
...
tensorboard (1.10.0)
tensorflow (1.10.0)
tensorflow-gpu (1.10.0)
...
```

and I get a very similar output by running `conda list`.

Python version is `Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda`.

Some other, hopefully useful, outputs:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()

2018-08-11 16:42:54.942052: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:897] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2018-08-11 16:42:54.943269: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GRID K520 major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.797
pciBusID: 0000:00:03.0
totalMemory: 3.94GiB freeMemory: 3.90GiB
2018-08-11 16:42:54.943309: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1455] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GRID K520, pci bus id: 0000:00:03.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.
2018-08-11 16:42:54.943337: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-08-11 16:42:54.943355: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0 
2018-08-11 16:42:54.943371: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N 
[]
```

.

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()

2018-08-11 16:44:03.560954: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1455] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GRID K520, pci bus id: 0000:00:03.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.
2018-08-11 16:44:03.561015: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-08-11 16:44:03.561035: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0 
2018-08-11 16:44:03.561052: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N 
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 15704826459248001252
]
```

.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()

2018-08-11 16:45:22.049670: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1455] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GRID K520, pci bus id: 0000:00:03.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.
2018-08-11 16:45:22.049748: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-08-11 16:45:22.049782: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971]      0 
2018-08-11 16:45:22.049814: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N 
False
```

Can you confirm that Keras is not running on GPU? Do you have any suggestion on how to eventually solve this problem?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I've tried to use a p2.xlarge EC2 instance, but the issues does not seem solved. Here are a couple of outputs

```
>>> from keras import backend as K
Using TensorFlow backend.
>>> K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
2018-08-11 21:54:24.238022: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-08-11 21:54:24.247402: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:406] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
2018-08-11 21:54:24.247430: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:145] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (ip-172-31-2-145): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
[]
```

.

```
>>> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
>>> device_lib.list_local_devices()
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 80385595218229545
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 6898783310276970136
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 4859092998934769352
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
]
```

Comment: The installed cuda version is too old. It requires Cuda>=3.5, you need to update the cuda version on the node or use a newer gpu (K520 is relatively old) on AWS.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. Do you have any pointer on how to update the cuda version? I did a search on G but is seems rather cumbersome to update those drivers so I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right direction. I will try to use a p2.xlarge instance, hope it will work.

Comment: hey @lmontigny I've updated my question with the tests I did on a more recent p2.xlarge EC2 instance. Would you be able to give me a feedback? Thanks again

Comment: Good that you solved the issue! Some info about the cuda installation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/aws/new-p2-instance-type-for-amazon-ec2-up-to-16-gpus/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing the following:

- using a p2.xlarge EC2 instance
- selecting [Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu) v12.0](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B077GCH38C) as starting AMI
- use `conda env list` to see the list of available environments and then activating the one I needed with `source activate tensorflow_p36`

This last point was probably the thing I never realized to do in my previous tests.

After that, everything was working as expected

```
>>> from keras import backend as K
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
>>> K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
['/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0']
```

Also, running `nvidia-smi` was showing the use of gpu resources during model training, the same with `nvidia-smi -i 0 -q -d MEMORY,UTILIZATION,POWER`.

In my sample case, training a single epoch went from 42s to 13s.